# Tenses used in title

Tags: tense, headlinese

> New York woman fights off rabid fox in her front yard, thought she would be 'eaten alive'

[Source: Yahoo News story by Adam Sabes August 25, 2022](https://www.yahoo.com/now/york-woman-fights-off-rabid-033648907.html?guccounter=1&guce_referrer=aHR0cHM6Ly93d3cuZ29vZ2xlLmNvbS5oay8&guce_referrer_sig=AQAAAD79fR1ffCEs4ulK1UD-Ut-GoXNPFKZgUwHPXkt7y3VgQ9kd0J2H6kiJEFsxNPb3ma__jhwF7mg4uhMSq8CljR0GKzZkuaZjVaoqPXxReyGzDaklY_CtUx3Hll0OZ46T5RDNLgK66gZFh85dJwefrbkF99irnqmpGeMpIi_wd9ym)

It's the title of that article.  I don't understand why the author uses the tense like that, i.e.  present tense along with preterite.`

Comment: It's usual to write news headlines in the present tense, to give them a sense of immediacy. In a traditional printed newspaper, the second part would probably have been a subheading in smaller type. The incident is over, so the lady doesn't still think she is going to be eaten alive. It's just one of those odd conventions of 'headlinese'.

Comment: @KateBunting Thank you.  It is okay if both were present tense or past tense. But it is the first time that I have encountered  two kinds of tenses are used in one headline, to indicate roughly the same time.  Now I understand since you  mentioned that the second part is more appropriate to be placed in subheading

Comment: If you're happy with my explanation, I will make it an answer.

Comment: A source link is better than nothing, but propere attribution consists of a title, author, and publication, which I have now added. Please include full attribution in future.

Comment: It's worth noting that headlines also use the infinitive to indicate the future "Mayor to run for Governor in next election".  There are a lot of weird conventions in writing headlines.  I was an editor of a student newspaper - headlines can be fun, but also frustrating (they have to fit)

Comment: She thought **before** she fought.

Comment: Technically it's not pure present tense, but more af a [historic present](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Historical_present).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's usual to write news headlines in the present tense, to give them a sense of immediacy.

In a traditional printed newspaper, the second part would probably have been a subheading in smaller type. The incident is over, so the lady doesn't still think she is going to be eaten alive. It's just one of those odd conventions of 'headlinese'.

Comment: So the incident is over in one part of the sentence, but still happening in another part of the same sentence??

Comment: @gidds It doesn't make much logical sense, does it? but headlinese often doesn't. Indeed English usage frequently doesn't.

Comment: @gidds I think the convention of present tense in headlines got started because it adds a sense of immediacy. It is strange to use present and past tense inconsistently in the same summary, and I would consider it an error.

Comment: @gidds - The journalist could have quoted her words in the subtitle - "I thought I would be eaten alive." But this is the way he chose to write it, no doubt working in a hurry.